# In app rating-Android

Tags: android, rating

Firstly, I am not a coding guy. So please explain to me like a 5 year old! :)
The problem that I am facing is that is it possible for an Android app to automatically recognize whether the user has rated that particular app on the play store or not? There are pop-ups etc which can guide the user to the play store page and rating can be done there, but does the app realize that it has been rated? If so, then is there a particular code that needs to be included wile developing the app?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple 5-year-old answer: No, there is no way to do this.

Comment: Thanks..That was easy enough!

Comment: I think Google will do this in the near future through a Google Play Services update. Following in iOS's recent in-app rating feature